# “Get Started” button does not appear for FB Messenger bot on Messenger app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, bots, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-graph-api-v2.6

For some reason, the "**get started**" button doesn't appear on mobile Messenger app but it works perfectly on web .
I have try to delete the button and re-post it . but still have the same problem. I used `node js` and I followed FaceBook's documentation:

[facebook get started button documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/thread-settings/get-started-button)

Anyone has a solution? Is it a bug?
Thanks a lot in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are certain conditions to seeing the Welcome Screen and the Get Started button:

- They are **only rendered the first time** the user interacts with the Page on Messenger
- Only admins/developers/testers of the app can see it when the app is in development mode
- Your app must be subscribed to postbacks on your webhook

These are the conditions mentioned in the documentation. Make sure they are satisfied.

There are two ways you can try to see the get started button:

- Try using the bot with a new user
- Clear all existing conversation with the bot, force close messenger app and relaunch it and start a conversation with bot

Comment: It works now i just closed the messenger app and relaunch it !! thank you