# How to add 'Get Started' button in facebook messenger chat bot?

Tags: chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot, payload

I tried using this

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "get_started": {"payload": "qr"} }' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=myPageAccessToken"
```

In response I also got  `{ "result": "success" }`

But the bot does not show any button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was working fine, All I had to do was, deleting the existing conversion.

In my case, get started button only appears, when there's no message exists in past.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that your account facebook who try to use your bot since only admins/developers/testers of the app can see it when the app is in development.

Second, if you use Android, you need to clear the Messenger data/cache under Android Settings -> Apps, this will also clear your login and you need to login again.

For further information, you could check this out: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42662751/6874563